# Parsing HTML with LINQ

Tags: c#, html, linq, html-agility-pack

I'm trying to take all cells from a HTML table using Html Agility Pack and LINQ.
I have loaded the HTML source in a HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument and selected the  tags with LINQ. However after using foreach to iterate the result, it crashes in the second record.

This is a fragment of the HTML source:

```
<tr>
    <td class='city'>New York</td>
    <td>Card 1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='city'>London</td>
    <td>Card 2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='city'>Tokyo</td>
    <td>Card 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class='city'>Berlin</td>
    <td>Card 4</td>
</tr>
```

And this is what I made:

```
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(await msgRecived.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

var tds=
    from td in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("td")
    where td.Attributes["class"].Value == "city"
    select td.InnerText;

foreach (var td in tds)
{
    citiesText = citiesText + " " + td;
}
```

It only return the first element, e.g. if instead of using foreach I do:

```
citiesText = tds.ElementAt(0);
```

It returns *New York*, but if I try ElementAt(1) it crashes with *Object reference not set to an instance of an object.*

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make sure that `Attributes["class"]` is not `null`:

```
var tds =
    from td in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("td")
    where td.Attributes["class"] != null && td.Attributes["class"].Value == "city"
    select td.InnerText;
```

The second `<td>` retrieved has no `class` attribute, so when you access `Attributes["class"]` in that case, you're getting `null`. Calling `.Value` on `null` is causing the exception.

Alternatively you could use `GetAttributeValue`:

```
var tds =
    from td in doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("td")
    where td.GetAttributeValue("class", null) == "city"
    select td.InnerText;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess but you are probably only looking at the td on the first element. Maybe you need

htmlDoc.DocumentNode.Descendants("table") instead.